# Show Localized price for In App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am using the following code in My ViewController, however when I call `_priceFormatter` it displays the price as `(null)`

```
 [buyButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upgrade for %@", [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

ViewController.m

```
{


    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;


}
```

ViewDidLoad

```
    [RageIAPHelper sharedInstance];

    _products = nil;

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;

        }
    }];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:0];


    ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]);

  _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

    [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

**EDITED**

```
_priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

NSString *priceString = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

**Button:**

```
    UIButton *buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 370, 320, 60)];
[buyButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upgrade for %@", priceString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
    [buyButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0]];
    [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buyButton.tag = 0;
    [[self view] addSubview:buyButton];
```

Comment: The call to `requestProductsWithCompletionHandler` is asynchronous. You are trying to access `_products` long before it is set.

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: Don't process the products until the completion handler is called.

Comment: Yes, but how do I change my code around to make that work?

Comment: See my answer. And BTW - why do you flag the product as purchased? This code does NOT purchase anything. It simply retrieves data about your products.

Comment: The code does allow the user to press the button to purchase

Comment: That's fine but you should call `productPurchased` when the user taps the button, not when you simply show the button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45673/discussion-between-omar-and-rmaddy)

Answer (score 6):

You need to wait until the completion handler is called to process the products:

```
[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance];
_products = nil;

[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
    if (success) {
        _products = products;

        SKProduct * product = _products[0];

        [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier];

        _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
        NSString *price = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
        someLabel.text = price;
    }
}];
```

And as you can see, you need to actually make use of the formatted number string. You were just throwing away the value.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question above to show you. I am still getting (null)

Comment: I used these code in my app, but why it always shows USD. I tried to change Language Setting on my iPhone, but didn't work. What's wrong with it?